# Firebase database snapshot to recycleview arraylist dynamically

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

My array:

```
private static String[] date = {
            "Mar 15",
            "Mar 22",
            "Mar 23" }; 
private static String[] type_d = {
            "Day",
            "Night",
            "Morning" };
```

Populate recycleview with array:

```
public static ArrayList getList() {

    ArrayList<TestModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
        testModel = new TestModel();
        testModel.setDate(date[i]);
        testModel.setType(type_d[i]);
        list.add(testModel);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This works perfect.
Now i'm trying to load exact data (in json like format) from firebase realtime database

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0) {

            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (map.get("type_d") != null) {
                type_d = map.get("type_d").toString(); //returns type normally
            }
            if (map.get("date") != null) {
                date = map.get("date").toString(); //returns date normally
            }
        }
```

my firebase data

```
{
"test": [
      {
        "type_d": "Day",
        "date": "20 Mar"
      },
      {
        "type_d": "Night",
        "date": "11 Mar"
      }
        ]
}
```

Q: how im gonna put this data to `testModel` ?

Comment: Ca you show: 1) where `dataSnapshot` comes from? 2) the JSON at that location int he database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 3) some kind of `Log.d` statement that shows the problem as printed output? Keep in mind that we can't see your screen.

Comment: no problems, i just cant figure it out or maybe its need to another approach like extract whole snapshot instead of every single string

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for (postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
     val post = postSnapshot.getValue<TestModel>()
     testModelList.add(post)
}
```

Comment: could you please in more detail ?

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you asked